# Problem With Scanner Mathod in Java: in.hasNext

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have the following program below. I wanted it to only run if the input is a string, so I used `hasNext()` with an if statement.

Unfortunately, it will still return true when I enter numbers. I want the program to execute the else statement if a letter grade is not entered. Is there a way around this? Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterGrade {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a letter grade: ");

        if (in.hasNext()) {
            String letterGrade = in.next();
            System.out.println(letterGrade);
        } else {
            System.out.print("Not a valid letter grade");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use,

```
Character.isLetter(char ch)
```

to determine whether the input is a letter.

When using the `System.in` as the `InputStream` source, you don't need to use `hasNext()` because it will not continue without an input.

And remember, `next()` method returns the user input as a String. It doesn't mean that it returns something only if the input is a String.

---

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a letter grade: ");

String letterGrade = in.next();

if (Character.isLetter(letterGrade.toCharArray()[0])) {
    System.out.println(letterGrade);
} else {
    System.out.print("Not a valid letter grade");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The .next() method of your scanner always returns a String, no matter what you type. In your case, the number you type in will be read and hold as a String object. You have to read the input first and after that you have to check if your input is a valid letter grade or not. I´d do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a letter grade: ");
    String input = in.next();
    if (isLetterGrade(input)) {
        System.out.println(input);
    } else {
        System.out.print("Not a valid letter grade");
    }
}

public static boolean isLetterGrade(String input) {
    //check if your String is a letter grade

}
```